# Magento 2 update column

Tags: magento2, collection, upgrade, crud

I have one cronjob needs to update status periodically.

Target table name is "Custom"

if custom table contain customid, user_id, status, exp_date columns.

I have scheduler php file call "custom.php".

I added below in __construct(

```
use Test\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\CollectionFactory

public function __construct(
     CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
     $this->collectionFactory=$collectionFactory;
}

public function execute() {
    $custom_obj = $this->collectionFactory->create();

    $custom_obj->addFieldToSelect('*')->load();
    $items = $custom_obj->getItems();

    foreach($items as $key=>$item){
         if( date("Y-m-d") > $item->getDataByKey("exp_date") ) {
              // save column
         }
    }
}
```

In this case does anyone know how to update column for this case ( to fill save column )?
Also, Does anyone know best practice for this kind of case for update?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
public function execute() 
{
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

    foreach ($collection as $item) {
         if ( date("Y-m-d") > $item->getData("exp_date") ) {
              $item->setCustomColumn('Data')->save();
         }
    }
}
```

If your column name is status, then

```
$item->setStatus('inActive')->save();
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer it. you meant if I want to change "Status" column then $item->setCustomStatus('inActive')->save() ?

Comment: Check updated answer. Should be $item->setStatus('inActive')->save();.